# how to get the path for executable file that started the application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am working on a web application using C#,

i know that in window application how to give the path for executable file that started the application (if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\gsdll32.dll")))

but i dont know how to give that path in web application using c#

please help me .

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET you use the [MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method:

```
var siteRootPath = Server.MapPath("~/");
```

Yet another possibility is to use the [ApplicationPhysicalPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath.aspx) static property:

```
var path = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```

Comment: my dll is in bin folder, so can i get the path for executable files or that dll

Comment: Isn't `Path.Combine(Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "bin"), "gsdll32.dll")` working for you?

Answer (score 0):

First thing you cannot run your executable from client end. It has to be a server side code which would run on server and for this you can use the similar logic.